# How to create two for loops in a terraform resource?

Tags: terraform

How to use for_each twice in a terraform resource?

In the following I want to iterate over all ec2 instances and add multiple tags everywhere.

```
# get ec2 instances
data "aws_instances" "ec2" {
  instance_tags = {
    "aws:eks:cluster-name" = var.cluster_name
  }
}

# tag ec2 network interfaces
resource "aws_ec2_tag" "ecs_node_eni" {
  for_each = toset(data.aws_instances.ec2.ids)
  
  resource_id = data.aws_instances.ec2.ids[each.key]
  #for_each = var.node_tags
  #key      = each.key
  #value    = each.value  
}
```

My variable for the tags looks like this

```
node_tags = {
      Environment    = "dev"
      Owner          = "MyName"
      ProjectName    = "MyProject"
      AppID          = "MyAppId"
      CostReference  = "MyCostReference"
  }
```

With the approach shown, I'm iterating over the ec2 instances, but I don't know how to get all the tags in "var.node_tags" to the instances.

Comment: It can't be done. Why do you want to loop over tags as well?

Comment: @MarkoE I would like to add all tags from my variable "var.node_tags" to each ec2 instance. The whole thing should be independent of the number of tags.

Comment: Can you add an example of tags variable to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will want to use `flatten` to create a flattened list of the tags per node.

```
locals {
  # Nested loop over both lists, and flatten the result.
  node_id_tags = distinct(flatten([
    for node_id in toset(data.aws_instances.ec2.ids): [
      for tag in local.node_tags : {
        node_id = node_id
        tag    = tag
      }
    ]
  ]))
}
```

Then loop over node_id_tags in the aws_ec2_tag resource.

References: [https://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2021/08/19/nested-for-each-with-terraform/#:~:text=Terraform%20does%20however%20support%20nested,suitable%20for%20use%20with%20for_each%20](https://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2021/08/19/nested-for-each-with-terraform/#:%7E:text=Terraform%20does%20however%20support%20nested,suitable%20for%20use%20with%20for_each%20).